# how to compare values between two collections and only render distinct values within a listbox using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, linq

within a form I have two listbox controls  these controls are used for mapping users to a role. Within the listbox on the left(available users) I need to show a list of all users associated to the current department. The listbox on the right displays a list of users from the department that are already mapped to the role.
[image]

Each listbox is mapped to it's own collection. What I would like to do is to filter out the names that may appear in the mapped users collection from the available users collection when the listbox initially loads. In looking at the illustration the listbox on the right should only display 1 available user for mapping to this role (In the illustration it would be alguser4)

My inital thought was to create a new collection (avaialbleuserscoll) and attempt to filter using linq. Where I am stuck is a user may be mapped to multiple roles therefore I can't take the current approach and just test for a count = 0. What I need to do is to test to ensure that the count is == 0 or that the role id does not equal the current roleid.

I'd appreciate any guidance on how to get only users that are not mapped to the current role to display in the listAllUsers listbox

```
 private void EditMappedUserDetails(int agencyid, int roleid)
    {
        List<SecurityUser> allUserColl;
        List<SecurityUser> mappedUserColl;
        List<SecurityUser> availableUserColl;
        allUserColl = AdminFactory.GetUsersAndRoles(agencyid).OrderByDescending(n => n.UserName).ToList();

        mappedUserColl = SelectedRoleData.FirstOrDefault().SecurityUserRoles.Select(r => r.SecurityUser).OrderByDescending(n => n.UserName).ToList();

        availableUserColl = allUserColl.Except(mappedUserColl).ToList();

        listAllUsers.DataTextField = "UserName";
        listAllUsers.DataValueField = "SecurityUserId";

        listMappedUsers.DataTextField = "UserName";
        listMappedUsers.DataValueField = "SecurityUserId";

        listAllUsers.DataSource = availableUserColl;
        listMappedUsers.DataSource = mappedUserColl;
        listAllUsers.DataBind();
        listMappedUsers.DataBind();
        editUserUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
```

Comment: the assignment of the datatext value being duplicated is because each each listbox is pointing to a separate collection and not the once. Also what is the benefit of setting this mapping in the markup vs. codebehind?   Thanks for the tips on the binding and assignment

Comment: Does it still display too many names in the "listAllUsers" listbox? (Make sure that builds have been pushed accordingly!) If the values are not expected, now would be a really good time to *attach a debugger with breakpoint* and see what values are in each variable (right before the DataSources are assigned would be a good spot).

Comment: @pst Yes updating the code to where the bindings match your example and the collections are bound properly I still receive all 4 users being rendered in the listAllUsers listbox.

Comment: It "looks okay". The last thing I can think of is to ensure that SecurityUser implements `Equals` **and** `HashCode` correctly.

Comment: @pst the only thing I can see is that mappedUserColl is IEnumerable and allUserColl is ICollection. Since these two are not of the same type could this be causing the issue with Except?

Comment: The container will not cause that issue, but items inside might if they don't implement the required equality contract. (See updated previous comment.)

Comment: `availableUserColl = allUserColl.Where(u => !mappedUserColl.Any(m => m.UserName == u.UserName)).ToList();` should be quick test to see if it's an issue with the equality implementation. (This does not consider the security-ID, mind.)

Comment: @pst The above works and only returns the one username (alguser4) that is not associated to the role but is part of the associated agency

Comment: Then the `SecurityUser` type does not correctly implement `Equals` and `HashCode`, which are used in `Except` (either that or they have different `SecurityUserId` values!) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the except function in linq to remove duplicates here is an example

```
 var m = availableUserColl.Except(mappedUserColl).ToList();
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that Except, Distinct, etc *do not guarantee result order*. For smallish values of `n`, where keeping the ordering is of importance, I thus often find myself preferring the trivial `available.Where(a => !mapped.Contains(a))` construct.

Comment: @cold-told The above example does not work . In you example you referenced availableUsersColl which is null or empty did not produce any results I modified the call to var m = allUserColl.Except(mappedUserColl).ToList(); which the allUsersColl contained a list of all the users. However this only produced a result list of all the users vs. what I would have expected to be just one result returned. What am I missing?

Comment: you must make sure taht both list have values  mappedUserColl              availableUserColl, allUserColl then after it all jield you are creating a new list var m = availableUserColl.Except(mappedUserColl).ToList() which you will bind to availableUserColL

Comment: @COLDTOLD in my last attempt allUserColl and mappedUserColl are both populated with values. availUserColl did not contain any values. You're saying that one should also be pre-populated before using Except()?

Comment: based on your code you use like another query like so     availableUserColl = (from au in allUserColl where ....... so it getting populate from this query in  listAllUsers therefore you have to make sure that the list  availableUserColl has values

Comment: @COLDTOLD ah my apologies in the original code that area was commented out and it did not translate across. I have updated the method with to the current working set. Please notice I have the Except() method in place this currently does not work it returns all five items

Comment: everything seems right the only think I can think is debug the results of your query

Comment: Using Except was the correct solution. After further digging the issue as to why it would not work in my implementation was due to different HashCodes on the collection.